# Expected throughput in Gigabit network

Tags: windows, networking, bandwidth, ethernet

I've been doing some tests with iperf to measure the network throughput between 2 servers (connected back-to-back thru a crossover cable) and I only see 180 to 200 Mbps. I tried different cables and they're all CAT6. As you may know, iperf generates packets on the fly so disk I/O is not involved here...

The two servers are running plain-vanilla Windows 2003 with the correct and latest network driver for the NICs.  I know there's some protocol overhead involved but I don't expect this to take more than 20% of the bandwidth.

Is it realistic to aim for 80% utilization? That is, to get around 800Mbps on a 1Gb link? Have you actually seen this on Windows?

Thanks,
JFA

Comment: What sort of servers?  If the processor is slow enough you might be bottlenecking at the CPU.

Comment: Also what sort of network cards are involved?

Answer (score 1):

I've seen sustained 950Mbps to a large Oracle DB on an iSCSI HBA under heavy load, but rarely above 500/600 Mbps for normal I/O on regular NICs. 300 Mbps is a more normal top speed of the day on my network though. YMMV.

Comment: Seems about right to me.

Comment: If anything, 300 for a given connection is higher than average.

Answer (score 1):

Turn on jumbo frames.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't answer your question but [THIS](http://www.tomshardware.co.uk/gigabit-ethernet-bandwidth,review-31611.html) is a great article from tomshardware.com that goes into detail about just how hard it can be for get into the 80%+ utilisation regions with GigE.

Answer (score 0):

I get that sort of performance on my hardware, but it's not the normal traffic. When I copy files between servers it gets sustained transfers however, I am not running server 2003.  [2008 has a much better networking stack](http://download.microsoft.com/download/8/E/D/8EDE21BC-0E3B-4E14-AAEA-9E2B03917A09/HSN_Deployment_Guide.doc) see the referenced whitepapaer for details on how to implement. Enabling jumbo frames wouldn't hurt either.

Answer (score 0):

Try checking to see if you are getting any Ethernet errors using **netstat** while running your test:

```
netstat -e
```

You'll get output that looks like this:

```
Interface Statistics

                                Received            Sent

Bytes                         1297481476      1525340409
Unicast packets                615329630       429473493
Non-unicast packets               809612           72735
Discards                               0               0
Errors                                 0               0
Unknown protocols                  44579
```

If you are getting a lot of *Errors*, you should try to track those down.

It may be verboten here, but try setting both cards to **Full Duplex** and see if you get a speed boost, or a reduction in errors.

You can also try **netstat -e -S** to get per protocol statistics (and errors) while running your test. It could be that your test utility is generating packets that are registering as problematic by Windows.

Answer (score 0):

It is important to note that these rates are, and always have been, based on a continuous transfer of the largest possible packet.  On the original Ethernet the claim was 10Mbps, but that was only true if every packet was 1500+ bytes long.